# How to enable SQL server data compression by code / with Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, compression

How can I enable database compression (supplied by SQL Server Enterprise edition) by code?

I have a large table and do not want to enable compression manually.

I'm using Entity Framework code first, so maybe there is some solution in database initializer?

Comment: No idea about EF but natively you would execute an `ALTER TABLE` with the `REBUILD` / `DATA_COMPRESSION` syntax

Comment: Ok, I see compression is no basic feature of some ORM.